# Write a query in TFS to identify who defects are against

Tags: tfs

Is it possible in TFS to write a query that can give me a list of who set a WI to a specific state "Ready for Test", and the defects that were raised as a result?

I'd like to be able to understand if there is any pattern to defects being identified.

Comment: Short answer is: it depends. What do you mean "and the defects that were raised as a result?" If the WI is still "Ready for test," can you just query Changed By? Are you using a custom process template? Do you have access to the work item type definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing a query, you can consider subscribing an alert. When `"State" Changes to "Ready for Test"`, send an email alert, you'll see this work item Changed by whom in the email:

[image]